# Why does BOOST_FOREACH not work sometimes with C++ strings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, string, boost

I am using BOOST_FOREACH to iterate through the characters of a C++ string like this:

```
void foobar(const string& str)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(const char ch, str)
    {
        // Do something with ch
    }

    return;
}
```

This piece of code works fine with the following compilation modes:

- Multi-threaded (Release) (/MT)
- Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
- Multi-threaded DLL (Release) (/MD)

It causes runtime errors (exceptions) only in this mode:

- Multi-threaded Debug DLL (Release) (/MDd)

There are no compilation errors or warnings with the above code snippet, leading me to believe that BOOST_FOREACH knows the container it is handling here. Also, changing `const char ch` to `const char& ch` has no change in the behaviour.

Why is this code causing this bad runtime behaviour?

Why only in the Debug DLL mode?

Is this usage of BOOST_FOREACH on C++ strings wrong?

If yes, what is the best workaround for it?

(Note that I am working with Visual Studio 2008 and Boost 1.39.)

Comment: Please give more detailed information about what kind of exceptions/errors you get, and at which point.

Comment: And also preprocessor output.

Comment: And a full minimal test case that reproduces problem.

Comment: Indeed, if you can get a testable program, many of us can test under those configurations.

Comment: I copy-pasted the code you gave us, and it worked fine on all the cases, including /MDd ... ^_^ ...

Comment: This is a related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881491/need-help-with-boost-foreach-compiler-bug

Answer (score 6):

Usage of BOOST_FOREACH on C++ strings is absolutely correct (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/foreach.html#foreach.introduction).
Looks like the issue in

```
  
// Do something with ch
```

Comment: +1 because : 1. The statement made me laugh. 2. The statement is most probably true.

Answer (score 2):

You should give us more information about your code, because:

- Your problem is tied with the VC++ runtime used
- As plainly answered by Dmitriy, your problem is most probably caused by the body of the loop

Anyway, with the little info you gave us, I could speculate the following:

- The fact the problem happens on debug and not on release is perhaps because a debug check discovered an error, memory corruption, whatever.
- The fact it happens only when you switch runtime, with STL code is perhaps you are mixing code from different modules, each one compiled with a different runtime

Of course, the fact your iterating over a const string means nothing should get modified, but as I was unable to reproduce your bug (pun intended), it is difficult to offer a definitive answer.

If you want more info, you need to provide us with the following info:

- Is the string object coming from another module (another DLL, another LIB, another EXE), possibly compiled with another runtime ?
- If you write the code by hand (using a plain old "for"), does it work ?
- What is the exact error message ?